# Accessing Google Cloud Function from Vercel Serverless Function

Tags: next.js, google-cloud-functions, vercel

I am seeking the best manner in which this should be done.

I have a https based GCF Function such as:

```
// google function
exports.someFunction = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    ...
    // some logic and access
    res.status(200).send(data)
  }
  catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message)
  }  

}
```

The API serverless function in Next.js is using axios. Is that the recommended method?

```
// next.js pages/api/call-google-func.js
async function handler(req, res) {
  try {
    const url = '....' //https://gcp-zone-project-xx834.cloudfunctions.net/someFunc
    const res = await axios.get(url)
    const resdata = res.data
    res.status(200).send(resdata)
  }
  catch(error) {
    res.status(400).send(error)
  }
}
```

The problem with this method is that the GCF must have public access. How can we set up to access the GCF from Next.js by passing credentials as environment variables. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think for this situation where a `Vercel Serverless Function` must communicate with the outside world, a `Google Cloud Function`, you'd want to create a [JWT](https://jwt.io/) token on Vercel's side to pass to Google's side which you would then need to verify. I think [Exchanging a self-signed JWT for a Google-signed ID token](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#exchanging_a_self-signed_jwt_for_a_google-signed_id_token) would be what you need.

Since either side doesn't know about the other, Google's IAM normal cloud privileges for allowing GCG<>GCF communication wouldn't apply here.